# Connection between Theodorus spiral and Archimedean spirals using an analytic expression

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

The figure below, made of right triangles with sides $1,\sqrt{n}$ and $\sqrt{n+1}$ spiraling around a common vertex (opposite side 1) beginning at $n=1$ is the (classical) "Theodorus spiral" ; see for example https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66969 .

[image]

I would like to establish that the limit curve is an Archimedean spiral.

Let us recall that such is spiral has a polar equation of the form :
$$\dfrac{\theta}{r}=a \ \ \text{ for some constant} \ a \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

$\bf{My} \ \bf{attempts}$ : My idea is to bring back this issue to the fact that the following limit exists :

$$a=\lim_{N \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{n=1}^N \mathrm{atan} \left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right) \ \ \ \ (2)$$

where the summation gives the general polar angle $\theta$ and $\sqrt{N}$ corresponds to radius $r$ in (1). Numerical computations give evidence for that with a value of $a$ looking slightly below $2$.

I have taken two ways :

- I have transformed the summation in (2) using relationship
  $$\mathrm{atan}(a)+\mathrm{atan}(b)=\mathrm{atan}\dfrac{a+b}{1-ab} \ \ \ \ \ (3)$$
  in a recurrent way, giving a single expression $\mathrm{atan}\dfrac{u_N}{v_N}$ through the double sequence :

$$\begin{cases}u_{n}&=&\sqrt{n} \ u_{n-1} & + & v_{n-1}\\
v_{n}&=&-u_{n-1}&+&\sqrt{n} \ v_{n-1}
\end{cases}, \ \ u_1=v_1=1 \ \ \ \ (4)$$

but I am blocked there...

2. I have attempted a different way by using Euler-Maclaurin summation formula (see Appendix below) using the fact that an antiderivative of function defined by $f(x)=\mathrm{atan}(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}})$ is given by $$F(x)=\sqrt{x}+x \  \mathrm{atan}(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}})-\mathrm{atan}(\sqrt{x}).$$

together with the development:

$$\mathrm{atan}(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}})=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\tfrac{1}{3 x \sqrt{x}}+\tfrac{1}{5x^2\sqrt{x}}- ...$$

which is a more rewarding direction...

---

Maybe, there other ways to prove that we have asymptotically an Archimedean spiral...

I would be grateful for any hint...

In fact, I discovered using the "Theodorus" keyword (that I hadn't when writing a first draft of this question) that the article
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_of_Theodorus provides a lot of information about this (not so trivial) issue...

---

**Edit** (Dec. 22, 2022) : I just discovered the exceptional book ["Spirals from Theodorus to Chaos"](https://archive.org/details/spiralsfromtheod0000davi/page/n9/mode/2up?view=theater) (Philip J. Davis with contributions from Walter Gautschi, A. Iserles
AK Peters, 1993) with answers to my questioning... and much more, all in a pleasant conversational style. I strongly advise it.

---

Appendix on Euler-Maclaurin formula : for any integers $a$ and $b$ with $0<a<b$ :

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k = a}^{b} f(k)  = \int_{a}^{b} f(t) \, dt  + \tfrac12 (f(a) + f(b)) + \sum_{n = 1}^{N} \frac{B_{2n}}{(2n)!} ( f^{(2n-1)}(b) -  f^{(2n-1)}(a) )  + R_{N},
\end{eqnarray}
where $B_{n}$ is the $n$th Bernoulli number with $B_{2} = \tfrac{1}{6}$, $B_{4} = -\tfrac{1}{30}$, $B_{6} = \tfrac{1}{42}$, etc... and
\begin{align}
|R_{N}| \leq    \frac{|B_{2N} |}{(2n)!}  \int_{a}^{b} | f^{(2N)}(t) | \, dt.
\end{align}
for any arbitrary positive integer $N$.

Comment: It is $\arctan$ in these circles, or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: @Christian Blatter Is your question about notation "atan" vs. notation "arctan" ? If yes, they are completely synonymous for me.

Comment: See this very interesting [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042709008012) by Walter Gautschi (one of the co-authors of the book mentionned upwards).

Answer (score 1):

*I do not know how much this could help you.*

Using Euler-MacLaurin summation
$$S_N=\sum _{n=1}^N \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$ $$S_N=2\sqrt N +C+$$ $$\frac{7}{6 \sqrt{N}}\left(1-\frac{41}{140 N}+\frac{167}{980 N^2}-\frac{1147}{9408 N^3}+\frac{1411}{14784 N^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{N^5}\right)\right)$$
For this level of expansion
$$C=-\left(\frac{3 \pi }{8}+\frac{48424865762593633}{49334034471321600}\right)$$ which seems to be quite decent.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 N & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 10^1 & 4.5236021 & 4.5254872 \\
 10^2 & 17.956659 & 17.958544 \\
 10^3 & 61.122767 & 61.124653 \\
 10^4 & 197.85200 & 197.85388 \\
 10^5 & 630.29955 & 630.30144 \\
 10^6 & 1997.8415 & 1997.8434 \\
 10^7 & 6322.3960 & 6322.3979 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

I did not find any solution for the double sequence.

Comment: In the amazing book by Philip J. Davis I mention, they give the following approximation, close to yours : $2 \sqrt{n}+C+\frac{1}{6 \sqrt{n}}+\frac{625}{4(n-1)^{\tfrac{3}{2}}}$ using as well Euler-MacLaurin.