# What function generates equally spaced points on a plane from circles

Tags: geometry

I have a program that generates circles of points (pixels) with increasing radii.
If for example the function is f(x) = x with starting at a reasonable value like 5.
Then the first circle has 5 equally spaced points. The second circle of 1 unit (pixel) greater radius has 6 points. The next circle has 7 points.

If you plot this function- you will see the field of points are not equally spaced.
The function xlog(x) **does** seem to be in the right direction.

However, I cannot think of a way to find a solution. Maybe there isn't one? Or maybe there is something fundamental I should know... but obviously am missing.

Any thoughts would be welcomed!

-adam

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, can you provide a plot?

Comment: Jean Marie below is on the right track... but still looking for a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a graphical representation with the case of 26 circles with radii :

$$r_n=n \ln(n), \ \ \ n=5 \ \text{to} \ 30 \tag{1}$$

[image]

*Fig. 1. Please note the parabolic alignments of the points on the right.*

This representation should help you to give a more precise content to your question : for example restrict at least this search to the points with negative abscissa.

In a second step, I suggest a criteria to be fulfilled : to have a pointspread the closest possible to a **hexagonal grid**.

A way to compare different solutions is to ask for the Delaunay triangulation then quantify all triangles regarding an "equilaterality degree/label" from "very good" to "very bad" (see  Fig. 2, 3 and 4 with Matlab program below) :

A good discrepancy index is obtained by taking :

$$ei=\frac{1}{2 \pi}(|\hat{A}-\hat{B}|+|\hat{B}-\hat{C}|+|\hat{C}-\hat{A}|)$$

(the closest $ei$ is to $0$, the closer to an equilateral triangle).

You have then to choose a threshold of "acceptability" and see how many "acceptable triangles" you have with this threshold, then change rule (1).

[image]

*Fig. 2 : Delaunay triangulation.*

[image]

*Fig. 3 : Being close to an equilateral triangle is measured by the "darkness of the blue".*

[image]

*Fig. 4 : Here, instead of rule $r_n=n (ln(n))$, we have taken $r_n=n (ln(n)-2)^3$. The result is better, compared with Fig. 3 (no yellow triangles ; few green ones).*

Matlab program :

```
clear all;close all;hold on;axis equal
P=[]; % points list
for n=5:20
   for k=1:n
      P=[P,n*log(n)*exp(i*2*pi*k/n)];
   end;
end;
% Delaunay triangulation :
K=delaunay(real(P),imag(P)); % K = list of indices of triangles
nt=size(K,1); % number of triangles
for k=1:nt
   Tr=P(K(k,[1,2,3,1])); % k-th triangle
   a=Tr(1);b=Tr(2);c=Tr(3);
   A=abs(angle((c-a)/(b-a)));
   B=abs(angle((a-b)/(c-b)));
   C=abs(angle((b-c)/(a-c)));
   ei=(abs(A-B)+abs(B-C)+abs(C-A))/(2*pi); % equilaterality index
   fill(real(Tr),imag(Tr),ei); % triangle interior painting
   plot(Tr,'k','linewidth',5); % triangle border
end;
colorbar;
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the plot of nLog(n). I think your idea of using these triangles to measure the degree of fitness for the solution is fantastic. However, it doesn't help me find the best function. My guess of nLog(n) is a total guess that I stumbled on. Can anyone find a better function?

Comment: You haven't answered about the region of the plane you are interested in. Visibly, the right hand side (quadrants I and IV) do not give satisfaction...

Comment: Yes, I agree that nLog(n) isn't the best answer- and certainly there is an asymmetry to the right side. This is in part due to the fact first point of each circle is along the same horizontal line. So I am in search of other functions (anything!) that does better. I have written a Galaxy cellular automata. You can see a video of it here:  https://www.adamblockstudios.com/articles/galaxy-cellular-automata  The distribution of points affects the results. I will certainly try your n(nLog(n)^3) idea!

Comment: This galaxy animation done by a cellular automata is splendid ! (I would be interested by knowing the rules behind, but maybe it is ongoing research). But I don't see very well the connection behind the problem you have described and the result you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you. The rules are simple. Supernova (white) trigger adjacent cells to start forming stars. Whether a cell is turned on is based on probabilities. Then you rotate each ring and iterate again. Thus, I construct the rings of cells of my galaxy as I describe above with a function...and I would like a function that results in rough isometric distances. Tiling the plane with hexagons would work as you suggest. But I construct my galaxy as rings of points on circles...so one function. See this old paper that is inspiration: https://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1976ApJ...210..670M

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Meanwhile, I have attempted to improve the approximation. I obtain rather good approximations with $n (\ln(n)-2.5)^{3}$

Comment: See my new fig. 4. Besides, about spirals vs. hexagonal packings, see this recent publication https://www.researchgate.net/publication/353069966_Packing_theory_derived_from_phyllotaxis_and_products_of_linear_forms (interesting but with a lot of theory...)

Comment: Thank you! The Vogel Spirals appears to be very close to what I am looking for...but I have no idea how I could rotate the points differentially! lol Anyway, I am satisfied enough through our discussion to conclude that tiling methods is where I need to look for answers. I am going to "check" this as a solution.

Comment: I have been interested by spirals for a long time. See for example my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3006165/305862). Have a look in particular to the book I mention from Philip J. Davis.

Comment: I checked that you solved the problem... why are they closing this question??

Comment: I don't know. The people closing the question should have seen, following our exchanges, in particular your spiral at adamblockstudios that you are on a serious work with these cellular automatas.